# GitLab Merge requests shows all commits and changes that already on the target branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, merge-request

I created a Merge Request to merge my source branch (develop) to the target branch (master), with the "Squash commits" option checked. Everything was fine, but now, when I try to create the same Merge Request (merge develop -> master) I run into the problem, that now I have ALL my previous changes and commits (from the previous merge request) + new commits and changes in the NEW Merge Request.
I know that squash creates new commit and it probably seems logical. But I've done the same things before and it worked fine.

Comment: You need to update your `develop` branch (I'm assuming that you worked on the same branch that you merged with squash option). If it's not the case, please clarify in question how exactly your branches look like.

Comment: In the end, I merged the new Merge Request with all these changes into the master branch, and everything seems to be fine. All of the previous changes were sort of "visual", that is, only visible in the mr, but not in the merge commit. I'm not sure what it was.

Comment: Everything is not fine and the problem is not merely visual. A squash merge is not a merge, so if you try to do multiple squash merges from one branch into another, you get the behavior you've complained about. What you're doing is wrong and you need to stop doing it.